# Button doesn't work on second click jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, webforms

I have a button that toggles a pop-up iframe whenever it is fired. The code is written on ASP.NET Webforms and jQuery

However, when I try to click it the second time, it doesn't fire anymore. I am wondering what is the cause of this.

Here is the jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {  
            var dStart = $("#MainContent_tbStart").val();
            var dEnd = $("#MainContent_tbEnd").val();
            var date = ("/Management/Site-Visit.aspx?StartDate=" + dStart + "&EndDate=" + dEnd);
            if (dStart != "") {
                $("#bSiteVisit").show();
                var SiteVisit = $("#iframeSiteVisit").html('<iframe id="iVisit" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>');
                $("#iVisit").attr("src", date);
                SiteVisit.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    bgiframe: true,
                    height: 600,
                    width: 1200,
                    modal: true,
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                        $("#iChart").remove();
                    }
                });
                $("#bSiteVisit").click(function (e) {
                    SiteVisit.dialog("open");
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            } else {
                $("#bSiteVisit").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the ASP.NET Code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button id="bSiteVisit" type="submit">View Site Visit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `e.preventDefault()` is not letting you to fire another click event of button. So click  will do nothing on submit button - form won't be submitted. Please modify it resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

### When button not woking in second time click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The button could also be disabled and have CSS that doesn't make that obvious.